# How to register a Popup if not using builder.Services

Tags: maui-community-toolkit

We're using Prism and its IoC Container with our MAUI application, and therefore are not using the built-in Maui Builder.Services.

The documentation for Community Toolkit Popups says to register a Popup and its ViewModel using the ServiceCollection extension `AddTransientPopup`:

`builder.Services.AddTransientPopup<UpdatingPopup, UpdatingPopupViewModel>();`

If we're not using builder.Services, how can we register our Popups so that the IPopupService knows about them?

Comment: Are you sure that the Maui version of Prism is supporting Popup?
https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/dialogs/mvvm-dialogs.html

Comment: Oh sorry, I also am using Community Toolkit Popup. So yes s.AddTransientPopup<LoginDialog, LoginDialogViewModel>();  LoginDialog : Popup  and PopupService.ShowPopupAsync<T>(); where T is the LoginDialogViewModel in this example.

Comment: So it looks like we can only use the built-in builder.Services with Community Toolkit popups.